# django was_published_recently error TypeError: cannot compare naive and aware datetimes

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, jython

I am learning Django on Jython and I have ran into an error while doing the [Django Tutorial 01](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

My System

- Windows 7
- jython2.7b2
- Django-1.7c3
- postgresql-9.3.5-1-windows-x64
- postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar

This is my code for models.py

from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
from django.db import models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question_text

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return self.choice_text
```

After inserting the objects into the database, I attempt the following commands.

```
>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q.was_published_recently()
```

I then get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\michmar3\workspace\pollsite\polls\models.py", line 14, in was_p
ublished_recently
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\datetime.py", line 1727, in __ge__
    return self.__cmp(other) >= 0
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\datetime.py", line 1765, in _datetime__cmp
    raise TypeError("cannot compare naive and aware datetimes")
TypeError: cannot compare naive and aware datetimes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `datetime.utcnow()` instead of `timezone.now()`

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it still didn't work.  So, I decided to open the project folder using an ide.  I opened it in eclipse's Pydev. I see that the line you told me to add was highlighted as an error.  But when I do datetime.datetime.utcnow() the method is available.  I then decided to do datetime.datetime.now() and run the test again.  It worked.  Does this mean something is wrong with my install or my paths?  How come I have to perform datetime.datetime to access the module?